# Not found page on browser

Tags: wordpress, openssl, localhost, apache2.4, port80

I installed a localhost (xampp) on windows 10 and also installed wordpress. So I tried accessing it with http://localhost/testsite
Then it displayed

Not Found
The requested url was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.52 (win64) openSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.1.2 server at localhost port 80

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does `testsite` folder (or file) exist under `C:\Program Files\XAMPP\htdocs` or `C:\xampp\htdocs`?  If not, [see this doc](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-local-wordpress-site-using-xampp/#:~:text=Creating%20a%20Local%20WordPress%20Site%20with%20XAMPP)